# How to store command results in a shell variable?

Tags: bash, shell

I want to find out the number of directories and files in home directory and store that in a shell variable. I am using the following set of commands.

```
command="ls -l | grep -c \"rahul.*patle\""
eval $command
```

I want to store the result in a variable. How can I do this?

Comment: you are probably better off using `ls -1` (number one) instead of `ls -l` and `grep -cE` depending on your system?

Answer (score 133):

The syntax to store the command output into a variable is `var=$(command)`.

So you can directly do:

```
result=$(ls -l | grep -c "rahul.*patle")
```

And the variable `$result` will contain the number of matches.

Comment: Is it possible to save the variable, but still keep the terminal output at the same time?

Comment: @Leo I don't think it is possible. You can probably use an intermediary file for this: `command | tee tmp_file` and then `var=$(< tmp_file)`. This performs the command; with `tee` you see it in terminal output and it is stored in the file `tmp_file` as well; then, you read the file into `$var`.

Comment: I just made it with an additional pipe `tee`. `result=$(ls -l | tee /dev/tty | grep -c "rahul.*patle")`

Comment: @Leo oh, that's a good one! I had just asked a question about it: [How to store the output of a command in a variable at the same time as printing the output?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37067895/1983854). Feel free to incorporate your comment there, to make it a general reference.