# How to print bash command output and save to file?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, command-line

I am writing bash script and inside I am executing a command. I want to save the output of the command to variable but also want to print the output of the command to the standard output. I dont want to print the variable once the command is completed. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Check `man tee`

Comment: Note that questions about *using* UNIX tools belong on [unix.se] or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/), not Stack Overflow. Our scope is specific to *developing* software.

Comment: This is also a duplicate of [How to store the output of a command in a variable at the same time as printing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37067895/how-to-store-the-output-of-a-command-in-a-variable-at-the-same-time-as-printing/37067964)

Comment: With Linux: `var=$(your_command | tee >(cat - >&255))`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Any reason you're not closing as duplicate?

Comment: @BenjaminW Already voted-to-close with a different reason so I can't.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following, it will print the output of your command and assign to variable.

`VAR="$(your_command| tee /dev/tty)"`

Comment: That's not printing *to standard output*, though, it's printing to the TTY.