# Bash function with parameters

Tags: bash, function, command-substitution

I am trying to understand how to work with functions (that receive a argument) in bash. I did not get my code to work, the following code exemplifies my difficulties:

```
#!/bin/bash

fruit_code () {
        if [[ "$1" == "apple" ]]; then
                code=1
        else
                code=0
        fi

        return $code
}


for var in apple orange banana apple; do
        code=fruit_code $var
        echo $code
done
```

The shell (bash) complains saying:

```
apple: command not found
orange: command not found
banana: command not found
apple: command not found
```

So it seems the passing of parameters is not working propperly. I can not see where I am going wrong. Any help is very much appreciated. Why does it not work? What changes shoyld I do to make it work? Wish to thank you all in advance.

Kind regards
Miguel

Comment: See: [How to store command results in a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19951369/3776858)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem is that if you want to execute a command and capture its *output* to a variable, you need to use command substitution:

```
code=$(fruit_code "$var")
```

The second problem is that your function doesn't write anything to standard output; it returns an exit status. That is automatically assigned to `$?` *after* you call the function. Use this instead:

```
fruit_code "$var"
echo $?
```

Finally, the convention in shell is for a 0 exit status to indicate success and a non-zero value failure. In this case, your function "succeeds" if the argument is *not* `apple`.

Comment: Hello, thanks that worked! However I tried with my functión returning strings and it did not work. Say for example that instead of my function returning 0/1 y want to return no/yes how would I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error in this line:

```bash
code=fruit_code $var
```

A syntax like this:

```bash
foo=bar quux
```

means that you want to run command `quux` in an environment where variable `foo` has value `bar`.

In your case, `quux` is `$var`, so it will take the value of `$var` and try to run it as a command. That's why you are getting errors saying `apple`, `orange`, etc. are not commands.

I think what you actually want is to run `fruit_code $var` and store the output in variable `code`, right?

In that case you can use this:

```bash
code=$(fruit_code $var)
```

or this:

```bash
code=`fruit_code $var`
```

I prefer the former because it looks clearer to me and allows easy nesting.

## Update: Returning strings in functions

Also, as noted by chepner on his answer and as you also noticed in a comment below, you are trying to use `return` for returning that string value as the result of the function, but `return` can only be used for returning numeric values as the result of the function (success / error / etc.) so you try to work it around by using numeric values that represent the strings you want to return.

That's overcomplex.

If you want to return a string, use `echo` instead and you can use `$()` or `` as explained above to capture the string returned by your function.

So, putting all this together, your code would look like this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

fruit_code () {
        echo $1
}


for var in apple orange banana apple; do
        code=$(fruit_code $var)
        echo $code
done
```

Comment: Hello, thanks that worked! However I tried with my functión returning strings and it did not work. Say for example that instead of my function returning 0/1 y want to return no/yes how would I proceed?

Comment: You have to use `echo $code` instead of `return $code` for returning strings. I just updated my answer with more details.