# I'm trying to put the output of the variable but it's getting an error

Tags: bash

I am trying to get the stylus id number of my device and I can't assign it in a variable.
If I echo it, the line of code is working.

```
GETSTYLUSID=`xsetwacom list devices`
echo $GETSTYLUSID | cut -d " " -f 7

IDSTYLUS=$GETSTYLUSID | cut -d " " -f 7

echo "put it in idstylus: $IDSTYLUS"
```

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/q/19951369/438992

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
IDSTYLUS=$(echo $GETSTYLUSID | cut -d " " -f 7)
```